# Magento : add external code to product view page

Tags: magento

i have an external script in phtml and i wanna add it right under the price-box div

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
        <catalog_product_view>
             <reference name="content">
                <reference name="product.info">
                    <block type="core/template" name="customprice" as="other" template="customprice/extJs.phtml"/>
                </reference>
            </reference>
        </catalog_product_view>
    </layout>
```

i have tried this in xml layout but it didn't work

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no need for two reference when you are adding or updating some blocks locally.
Try this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
            <reference name="product.info">
                <block type="core/template" name="customprice" as="other" template="customprice/extJs.phtml"/>
            </reference>
 </catalog_product_view>
```

And in your view.phtml file call this where you want the block to appear

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other'); ?>
```

Comment: no working and i don't want to edit the core because i m developping an extension

Answer (score 0):

the quick n dirty way, paste this in your view.phtml or whereever.

```
<?php echo $this->setTemplate('customprice/extJs.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@James,  there's no need to call the block defined as "other" explicitly.  It is already defined in view.phtml

Comment: you are right. My bad. @Souf you don't have to call the `getChildHtml`